# Pattern matching problem in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like "AAA  101  B202  C      303  " and I want to get rid of the space between char and number if there is any. 
So after operation, the string should be like "AAA101  B202  C303  ". But I am not sure whether regex could do this?

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with regular expressions. Here's a short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "A 101 B202 C 303 ";
        string output = Regex.Replace(text, @"(\p{L}) (\d)", @"$1$2");
        Console.WriteLine(output); // Prints A101 B202 C303
    }
}
```

(If you're going to do this a lot, you may well want to compile a regular expression for the pattern.)

The `\p{L}` matches any unicode letter - you may want to be more restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
([A-Z]+)\s?(\d+)
```

And replace with

```
$1$2
```

The expression can be tightened up, but the above should work for your example input string.

What it does is declaring a group containing letters (first set of parantheses), then an optional space (\s?), and then a group of digits (\d+). The groups can be used in the replacement by referring to their index, so when you want to get rid of the space, just replace with $1$2.

Comment: Why make the space optional? After all, that's what this is all about.

Answer (score 0):

While not as concise as Regex, the C# code for something like this is fairly straightforward and very fast-running:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<s.Length; i++)
{
    // exclude spaces preceeded by a letter and succeeded by a number
    if(!(s[i] == ' '
        && i-1 >= 0 && IsLetter(s[i-1])
        && i+1 < s.Length && IsNumber(s[i+1])))
    {
        sb.Append(s[i]);
    }
}
return sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun (because the act of programming is/should be fun sometimes) :o) I'm using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) with [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx):

```
 var result = text.Aggregate(
 string.Empty,
 (acc, c) => char.IsLetter(acc.LastOrDefault()) && Char.IsDigit(c) ?
 acc + c.ToString() : acc + (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && char.IsLetter(acc.LastOrDefault()) ?
 string.Empty : c.ToString())).TrimEnd();
```